# Grails get session variable from domain validator

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class, grails-validation

Im sure this is a common scenario, but I haven't found any answers. I have a session-scoped variable that holds the currently signed in user and I need to perform conditional validation by way of a custom validator in a domain object. Is there a way to get the the current user from the session scope while in a validator, or is there perhaps another way to do this, keeping in mind that I want to be able to return the errors for specific fields from my validator(e.g. `if(isBlank(it))return ['blank','summary',Presentation];`)

basic struture:

```
class MyDomain 
{
    String aProperty;
    static constraints =
    {
        aProperty(validator:{
        if(isAdmin())return true;
        if(isBlank(it))return ['blank','summary',Presentation];
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to validate? Using the session from within a domain isn't very typical; you'd normally want to do that in a service, or somewhere higher up. Domains usually shouldn't care about what's happening with your container sessions.

Comment: Its just a standard Domain class with properties that require less strict validation for admins than for normal users

Comment: I added a sample of what im trying to do, the question is how to implement the isAdmin function

Comment: Gotcha. An interesting use case. I haven't written any validation that changes with the current logged-in user. I'll have to think about it for a while.

Comment: Are you using spring-security-core?

Comment: no this is an internal app and spring-security-core is not necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this post: http://www.mosbase.com/2011/07/grails-accessing-http-session-from.html

Comment: Adding a service looks like it could be worth a shot. Ultimately the service has to be able to somehow get the context of the session through the call trail though which im not sure it can do without being session scoped. Still it warrants further research

Comment: You could also just access it directly with `RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().session`

Comment: Got it hooked in and it does indeed work. Had to use a lot of try catch though, but it will do. Thanks